# Existence of operator - From "Symmetry breaking" book by Strocchi

Tags: representation-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, quantum-field-theory

In the book "Symmetry breaking" by Strocchi, in the chapter were he introduces the Fock representations for C*-algebra of bounded operators over a Hilbert space (Part II, chapter 2, page 76), he proves that two irreducible Fock representations $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ of the same algebra $\mathcal{A}$ are always unitarily equivalent. However, there is one step in his proof that I don't fully understand.

He says that, given $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ Fock vectors (also known as vacuum states) for, respectively, the irreducible representations $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$, it is possible to define an operator $U$ such that

1. $U \psi_1 = \psi_2$;
2. $U \pi_1 (A) \psi_1 = \pi_2 (A) \psi_2, \, \forall A \in \mathcal{A}$.

He says also that since the representations are irreducible, then $U$ and its inverse are defined on dense sets.

Then the proof continues, but I don't understand why it is possible to say that the operator $U$ is well-defined, and why it is invertible.

Any idea?

Comment: The result is not true in general, so it has to depend on properties of $\mathcal A$ and/or how $\mathcal A$ acts on each of the spaces.

Comment: Ah ok, that is interesting, thank you @MartinArgerami. The only thing that is in the book is that the algebra is the algebra of bounded operators acting on a Hilbert space. The degrees of freedom can be either finite or infinite. Are these properties sufficient for the statement above?

Comment: I would be surprised if you $\mathcal A$ is $B(H)$, the algebra of all bounded operators. Because such algebra only depends on the dimension of the Hilbert space $H$, so you wouldn't have different algebras for different degrees of freedom, and it is **not** generated as a C$^*$-algebra by finitely many operators (not even countably many).

Comment: Ok, then which conditions are necessary to have the existence of the operator $U$ defined above, and to have it also invertible? Maybe I missed something in the book, or it is implicit (and I did not know it)

Comment: If a unitary $U$ exists as you want, you need that $\|\pi_1(A)\psi_1\|=\|\pi_2(A)\psi_2\|$ for all $A$. This condition is necessary and sufficient; it makes $U$ isometric and the irreducibility then guarantees that, being linear and defined on a dense subset, it extends by continuity to the whole space. The invertibility is automatic once you have a linear isometry with dense range.